# Error on socket shutdown: [WinError 10038] An operation related to an object that is not a socket

Tags: python, sql, sockets, plotly-dash, clickhouse

I have this following problem:
I'm am doing (at the same time) to sql request from the same database and the second request is depending from the result of the first:
e.g.

```
def get_alldata(timestart):
    statement = f""" SELECT * FROM "xxx"."xxx" WHERE timestart>=toDateTime('{timestart}')"""
    df = client.query_dataframe(statement) #note that i already defined my 
                                 #client from clickhouse and it works
    return df

#now the second
def second_request(id, time, line):  #note that i get the id,time and line from the table(df) of 
                                     #the first function (i'm working 
                                     #with dash plotly) so i saved df in a Store and used it for 
                                     #the second function
    statement = f'''SELECT student,class FROM "xxx"."xxx" WHERE id IN ({id}) AND time IN ({time}) AND line IN ({line})'''
    df = client.query_dataframe(statement)
    return df
```

The first function works in my app but when it comes to the second i get this error:

**Error on socket shutdown: [WinError 10038]  An operation related to an object that is not a socket**

and also **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'**

I tried a bit to look online about socket but i didn't find something in relation with my issue

Has someone an idea??

I call the function in two callbacks from dash

```
@app.callback(Output('id', 'options'),
              Output('time', 'options'),
              Output('line', 'options'),
             [Input('loaded_data', 'data'),
]
)
def get_first_fuction(data):
    df = get_alldata(data) # then i used it for a dropdown for the three outputs
.
.
@app.callback(
     Output('graph', 'children'),
     [Input('id', 'value'),
      Input('time', 'value'),
      Input('line', 'value'),
]
)
def second_function(id,time,line):
    df = second_request(id,time,line)
    # and i use it for a plot
    # I get the error by this df
```

Answer (score -1):

maybe you close the cursor and/or the connection between the execution (call) of those functions ? i guess functions seems ok but could you show the whole programm or at least the part where you actually call the functions ?

Comment: It is not an answer but a comment. Please consider adding a comment here.